# boundary of a boundary equals boundary if the set is closed

Tags: general-topology

how can I prove that $ \partial \partial A =\partial A $ given that A is closed?

I already know the easy direction: $ \partial \partial A  \subseteq \partial A $ for every set A.
Thanks!

Comment: Does the boundary have any interior points? If not then its boundary will also be the same.

Comment: what definition of $\partial A$ do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\partial A=\bar A-A^o$ where $A^o$ is the interior of $A$. If $A$ is closed, $\bar A=A$, thus $\partial A=A-A^o$. $\partial\partial A=\overline{\partial A}-{\partial A}^o=\overline{A-A^o}-(A-A^o)^o$. But $A-A^o=A\cap C(A^o)$ is closed if $A$ is closed since the complement $C(A^o)$ of $A^o$ is closed we deduce that $\overline{A-A^o}=A-A^o$ . We have also $A-A^o\subset A$, this implies that $(A-A^o)^o\subset A^o$. Since $(A-A^o)^o\subset A-A^o$, we deduce that $(A-A^o)^o\subset (A-A^o)\cap A^o$ this implies that   $(A-A^o)^o$ is empty. thus $\partial\partial A=\partial A$.